# How much space does Ubuntu use on a persistent pendrive with the updates?

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

This might have been asked here before......but I am wondering how much disk space on my pendrive an updated Ubuntu 12.10 OS will take up.

I have reserved 3.5 GB for it but it gave me an error message during the update that that wasnt enough.

I want to know this so that I may choose the adequate pendrive size.

Comment: I seem to remember a limit of 4GB for the persistence file anyway.

Comment: 4G is for making a persistent USB pendrive using the "Startup Disk Creator". But then if you wanna put the updates on that persistent driver....then you get surprised....because it requires a lot of space. But I guess I'll test it myself now and update my post. Thanks a lot @guntbert anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A Full install of 12.10 will work on an 8GB stick leaving about 3 1/2 GB for data, updates etc.

A persistent install will work on a 4GB stick, but don't do updates, they will quickly fill the drive and make it unbootable.  The max size of the casper-rw persistence file is 4GB, (unless you are using persistent casper-rw and home-rw partitions).

If you absolutely need to do mass updates do a Full install.